# Тонкости работы с функцией strdup

Tags: c++, c

Создаст ли `strdup()` `'\0'` в конце динамического массива?

```
char buf[128];
buf[0] = 'x';
for(int i = 1; i < 64; i++)
{
    buf[i] = i;
}
char *str = strdup(buf);
```

Comment: Откуда ж по вашему `strdup` сможет узнать, где именно создавать этот `\0`?

Comment: продублиует  пусту строку. 0 в первом элементе.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во первых, у Вас опечатка в последней строке:

```
char *str = strdup(duf); // Надо buf
```

А во вторых, достаточно сделать *man 3 strdup*, что бы прочитать:

```
ОПИСАНИЕ
       Функция  strdup()  возвращает  указатель на новую строку, являющуюся дубликатом строки s.
       Память под новую строку выделятся с помощью malloc(3) и может быть высвобождены с помощью
       free(3).

       Функция strndup() похожа на предыдущую, но копирует не более n байт. Если s длиннее n, то
       копируется только n байт и добавляется конечный байт null ('\0').
```

Отсюда делаем выводы:

1. Раз речь идёт о **строке** (в понимании С), то символ '\0' **обязан** присутствовать в исходной строке. (Ошибка в Вашей программе)
2. Если строка слишком длинная, то *strndup* автоматически вставит этот символ куда нужно.

Comment: Опечатку поправил. Вопрос был именно про статический массив; в вашем ответе прямого ответа на вопрос не было, потому не принял и ответил сам.

Comment: @LevayaNogaKabargi помоему все ясно было, статический массив от динамического тут не отличаеся. Функция принимает адрес начала массива, моэтому единственный способ найти конец - это нулевой символ.

Answer (score 2):

При `i = 0`; `buf[i] = i;`
`strdup` создаст пустую строку. Ноль является признаком конца строки и всегда копируется, как сказано в документации. Аргументом функции является указатель, а слдовательно функция не "знает" размера массива. `strndup` сделает то же самое, он обрезает строку и добавляет нулевой символ только если не встретит его до n-го элемента.

И откуда такая кривая реализация  strdup в ответе? Обычно он реализован вот так

```
char *strdup(const char *s)
{
  size_t len = strlen (s) + 1;         // длина строки включая нулевой символ
  char *result = (char*) malloc (len);
  if (result == (char*) 0)             // или if (!result)
    return (char*) 0;
  // мы уже знаем длину строки и хотим использовать RVO
  return (char*) memcpy (result, s, len); 
}
```

либо с использованием встроенных функций. strcpy - потеря времени когда длина строки известна.

Вызов strlen(s), если начиная с адреса s нет нулевого символа в пределах указуемого массива, является  источником неопределенного поведения.strdup и strlen являются источниками потенциальных дыр безопасности именно из-за этого, strdup в большей мере т.к. он позволяется информации "утечь" куда-то в результате копирования.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, у `LevayaNogaKabargi` вполне допустимый вариант реализации `strdup`... довод в пользу использования `memcpy()` вместо `strcpy()` (а по сути разница только в этом) только один — он несколько быстрее на «современных больших железках» для большого объёма данных.

Comment: Так что в «больших» libc ([glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strdup.c) и [FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/string/strdup.c)) используется именно он. А автор [avr-libc](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/libc/string/strdup.c) напротив решил использовать `strcpy()`. Но вся эта разница настолько эфемерна, что на самом деле ни кто не парится ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer вообщето как раз оттуда и стянуто. И memcpy не просто быстрее, компилятору позволено заменчть его на вызов встроенной функции, а следовательно единственной инструкции процессора. А еще не надо создавать лишнюю переменную, или провоцировать каст (void*)0 в (char*)0

Comment: Я плюсанул, но зачем так много букв (и приведений типов)? Достаточно `if (result) memcpy(result, s, len); return result;`

Comment: @avp  не уверен, но скорее всего связано с построением  компилятора. NULL, это же макрос из <cstddef>, на этом этапе не определен. А там он определен как (void*)0 для С. Код компилируется как в С так и в С++, а правила приведения разные.  Mingw-реализация делает второй вариант, например. В  до-С99 коде  можно было  вообще ничего не приводить, в С++ обязательно нужно и надо использовать nullptr а не NULL. В любом случае `return memcpy(result, s, len);` лучше чем двухстрочный вариант.

Comment: @avp return result добавляет дополнительную операцию копирования и еще одну зависимость на ветвлениях. Учитывая что проверка того что указатель - ноль, м.б. сложной, тут не все так просто- указатель не являтся числом на некоторых платформах.

Comment: @Swift, да, давно не смотрел на код (ассемблер) для ***x86*** (забыл, что результат функции в `rax`, а первый аргумент в `rdi` (в *arm* и *mips* оба в **R0**)) / Поэтому придется подсказать компилятору, как правильно оптимизировать и просто после `malloc()` написать `return result ? (char *)memcpy(result, s, len) : result;` (впрочем, оно еще и покороче (но не факт, что наглядней для любого человека) получилось)

Comment: Впрочем, все это пустое, "кодегольф", разминка для хвоста, так сказать -)

Answer (score 0):

Нет! Функция `strdup` предназначена для работы со **строками** потому самостоятельно добавить символ конца строки не может, однако если массив уже имеет `'\0'` функция скопирует его.

```
char buf[128];
buf[0] = 'x';
for(int i = 1; i < 64; i++)
{
    buf[i] = i;
}
buf[64] = '\0';// ←←← как-то так
char *str = strdup(buf);
```

Фактически функция `strdup` эквивалентна следующему коду:

```
char *strdup (const char *s) 
{
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Space for length plus nul
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          // No memory
    strcpy (d,s);                        // Copy the characters
    return d;                            // Return the new string
}
```

Comment: В дублированной строке всегда будет завершающий ноль на той же позиции, что и во входной строке. `buf[64] = '\0';` не имеет смысла так как в `buf` уже есть завершающий ноль.

Comment: эта реализация strdup вызывает strlen дважды. А еще NULL обычно не используют

Comment: фактически функция далеко не так реализована.

Comment: @Swift, где ты увидел второй вызов `strlen()`? а использование `NULL` зачастую даже требуется стайлгайдами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer strcpy либо реализуется этим же способом что и вышеуказанная функция, вызывая  strlen и memcpy, либо выполняет эквивалентную работу. То есть итерирует по массиву пока не встретит ноль. Memcpy  может быть приведен к одной операции процессора - копипование блока памяти! NULL может быть 0, (void*)0, nullptr, и пр. Стайлгайды на C++ а разрвботка разработка корневых библиотек или ядра отдельная кузня. У меня в ответе приведен реальный код функции с той реализации что была под рукой